# Number of winners in a one-round tournament where everybody plays everybody else

Tags: python

The task is as follows:

> N teams participated in a one-round tournament without draws (each played one match with each). All teams that have won no fewer games than the rest are considered winners. What is the largest number of winners in such a tournament?

I tried the following:

```
N = int(input())
if N % 2 != 0:
    print(N)
else:
    print(int(N / 2))
```

but failed. The tester indicates that just 7% of answers are correct.
Can you please be so kind to explain, how to think, and maybe how to solve this?

Comment: The code you wrote checks if some number is not even and prints it, or prints half that number otherwise - it's unclear how that relates to the question at all. What part of the actual problem are you having trouble with? How would you answer the question without writing code? Do you understand what the question actually means?

Comment: I can't figure out the correct algorithm, I think... 
It was clear for me that if we have odd quantity of teams, all of them can win same quantity of games. For example, if we have 3 teams, each team has one win and one lose. So, we have 3 winners. With the same logic, if quantity of teams is even only half of them might be a winner. Easiest example - two teams: one is winner, another - not.

Comment: @John Kugelman
Yes, 9 winners in case of 9 team. 4 wins and 4 loses each team.
*All teams that have won no fewer games than the rest are considered winners.*

Comment: @sidcoder the task is to count the largest possible number of winners in such a tournament, even if this case seems to be rare ;)

Comment: Maybe this question belongs to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: @VladimirFokow The task is from the "easy tasks for Python beginners"...

Comment: If there are 4 teams, 3 of them could have a 2-1 record and the 4th could be 0-3. A beats B, B beats C, C beats A, and everybody beats D.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Arrrrgh... that's right. I didn't think about it. Well, what's algorithm should be in this case, John?

Comment: I don't know, it's trickier than it appears at first glance. It's a fun puzzle. Keep working at it. :)

Comment: Maybe the algorithm that exhaustively checks all the possible options (of who wins over who)...

Comment: For N=2 the answer is 1, and for N=4 it's 3. I would work out the answer for N=6 and N=8 by hand and see what pattern emerges. Can the N=4 result repeat for higher N where one team loses to everyone?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thank you for the correction of my question and I'm very sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @JohnKugelman WOW! Sure, In case of 6 teams - 5 are winners. I mean it's possible. Same for 8 (7  are winners) etc. Was absolutely not obvious for me. Thank you once again for the idea.

Comment: Is this online for testing somewhere?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, it's here:
[link](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=3309&chapterid=3482#1)

Comment: Ugh, registering wasn't too hard, but now they don't have an online editor. Does your new strategy get accepted? I think it should, but it's odd that you had only succeeded 7% of the time instead of 50%...

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes it's accepted and I received 100 points for the answer (12 tests done and all successfully). So, the task is solved like:
'''N = int(input())
if N % 2 != 0:
    print(N)
else:
    print(N - 1)'''

Comment: Hmm, 1/12 = 8.333...%, so I'm really baffled that you got 7%. Anyway, answers should go into answers and [you can answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).